# 'Find and replace' between two xml files

Tags: xml, replace

Here's an example.

File 1:

```
<entry>
    <uselesstag1>data!</uselesstag>
    <identifier>entryname<identifier>
    <uselesstag2>data</uselesstag>
    <uselesstag5>moredata</uselesstag>
    <importantdata>8</importantdata>
    <uselesstag3>somemoredata<uselesstag>
</entry>

[...]
```

File 2:

```
<entry>
    <uselesstag6>yetmoredata</uselesstag>
    <identifier>entryname<identifier>
    <uselesstag3758>data</uselesstag>
    <uselesstag25>moredata</uselesstag>
    <uselesstag100>whynotmoredata<uselesstag>
    <importantdata>0</importantdata>
    <uselesstag603>stilldata<uselesstag>
</entry>

[...]
```

What I want to do is the following:

If the data in `<importantdata>` is 0 in the second file but not in the first, replace it with the value of the first file.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What programming language / environment do you intend to use? Have you already tried to solve that problem yourself? If yes: show your attempts so far, if no: try it first.

Comment: I don't really know where to start from...

Comment: I'm actually on Ubuntu Linux, but I can use Windows as well.

Comment: Your xml file is even not valid. Tags are not closed correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what programming language you use, here is a C# solution.

```
        //Load your xml files first
        XmlDocument doc1 = new XmlDocument();
        doc1.Load("file1.xml");
        XmlNode root1 = doc1.DocumentElement;

        XmlDocument doc2 = new XmlDocument();
        doc2.Load("file2.xml");
        XmlNode root2 = doc2.DocumentElement;

        //Find <importantdata> in each xml document
        XmlNode importantDataInFile1 = root1.SelectSingleNode("/entry/importantdata");
        XmlNode importantDataInFile2 = root2.SelectSingleNode("/entry/importantdata");
        string value1 = importantDataInFile1.InnerText;
        string value2 = importantDataInFile2.InnerText;
        //If the data in <importantdata> is 0, replace its value with value1 
        if (value2.Equals("0") && !value1.Equals("0"))
        {
            importantDataInFile2.InnerText = value1;
            doc2.Save("file2.xml");
        }
```

It's not a difficult question, I think you can make it work. Hope it helps.